# Google play services out of date on a virtual machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I'm trying to make an application using google maps, but in the emulator it does not work in console I see the following error:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1041): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 3136130
```

On screen I see that I have to update google services ..

My virtual machine is 4.2.2

What do I do? I've searched the forums here .. but no solution that I've tried has worked ..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. check the docs. Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform.
If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.
Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.

Comment: i fix it, i install new version of google play services, exact: 3.1.59

Comment: glad if it works for you.

Comment: If you figured out how to fix it, it would be a good idea to write that up as an answer so that people can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform. Open the sdk manager and check if you have the updated Google play services.(assuming you use eclipse)

Quoting from the docs.

If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, **select Google APIs**, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.

Note: **Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.**

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Check the topic under `Ensure Devices Have the Google Play services APK`.

Make sure you have the latest updates

Comment: I have done everything it says, but still does not work, I have my machine with Google APIs and the project too ..

Comment: You cannot use the Google API's with the Play Services.

Comment: @dbasch i merely quoted from the docs. the note is quoted from the docs. I have also posted the link and the link has a note. pls check the same.

Comment: @dbasch i even tested maps on emulator 4.2.2  which requires google play services and google api's. So what's quoted in the docs in right and that what i have posted.

Comment: @dbasch sure give it a try. it should work unless there is something missing in the docs.

Comment: @Raghunandan. Can you share the Google Play Services APK's that you are installing to the emulator?

Comment: I din't install anything i just downloaded the latest google play services. and i used google api version 17. its included

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34320/discussion-between-dbasch-and-raghunandan)

Comment: I think you are using an outdated version of Google Play Services. The bug is confirmed by Google here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=57880

Comment: @dbasch no i have the latest google play services. could be an issue.

Comment: @dbasch i do have google play services rev 9. i am cross checking again by running the map app. also op commented "i fix it, i install new version of google play services, exact: 3.1.59".

Comment: @dbasch i just opened the map apps(by google) on the emulator it works

Comment: It must not be a consistent bug. I have the bug with rev 9 and Google API 17.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Google issue. Check this out - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880

They've posted a message saying that they will post the updated play services soon. Till then (as of 31 July) you won't be able to run the Google Maps API on your emulator even if you do all the steps required.

Edit: As of September 2013, they've launched an update for it..

Answer (score 0):

In your SDK manager, make sure you've downloaded the latest 'Google play services' or alternatively download them manually and adb install onto the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating a new avd with target version as : Google APIs(GoogleInc) API Level 18. (platform 4.3 google api required)