# Any Latest solution to Run google play Services v2 app on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an app that is using Google play services v2. ( map related ). when i run my program on emulator, it give a message like "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services."
i try many solutions but no success. i tried these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar) and [this solution](http://blog.kerul.net/2012/08/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android.html) .
Please suggest some other trick to run app on emulator.

thanks and regards

Comment: what is the android version on emulator? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: i tried on all from API 15 to 17

Comment: pls check the docs and the note  Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services

Comment: Just tried it all again but no fruit...

Comment: i have quoted from the docs this is what i know. wait for someone to suggest a better answer which will probably give you fruit.

Comment: This is the latest position on this (or you can subscribe to the bug fix to get status updates emailed to you):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858215/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3159100-but-found-3158130/17886856#17886856