# Google Play services out of date. (On Device, NOT avd) Device has most recent version available

Tags: android, google-play-services

My app uses maps v2, and has been working great. My device has the latest version of Google Play Services. And the SDK Manager shows Rev 11 for the library. I updated to adt 22.2 yesterday, and since, I get this in LogCat:

```
Google Play services out of date. Requires 3264100 but found 3225132
```

And the app prompts with "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services". Not so bad, except that there's no way to update, given the device already has it installed. I uninstalled, and reinstalled Google Play service, and confirmed it's running the latest from the store, 3.2.25 Again, this had been working great ever since implementing maps several months ago.

My sdk settings in manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I've tried various combinations of min/target in desperate attempts to resolve this.

In code, I used GooglePlayServicesUtil to verify; system thinks the app needs to update to 3264100

I've searched quite a bit, but most everything I've found relates to issues when running on an avd. What can I to do to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you are logged into play store. I faced the same issue but this solved mine

Comment: Thanks Ravi; I really wish it were that simple, but I am logged in. Ugh, so frustrating at times;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, got it. Issue was related to updating, but I hadn't updated the tools in a while, so Rev11 of google play services is no good. See this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880#makechanges)

In short, rev 11 requires a version of the app not yet released, and google had pulled it, and I didn't realize that. So, in case anybody else hits this:

1. Launch SDK Manager
2. Check google play service, and check it if it's Rev 11
3. Delete the package
4. Reload the manager via menu
5. Install Rev 10, which they've reverted to in the meantime

Comment: Link to original question that lead to solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909278/google-play-services-out-of-date-on-device-not-avd-device-has-most-recent-ve answer by IanB, who really deserves the credit in my opinion