# Google Play services and Google maps error

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

```
10-09 12:56:30.461: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(14202): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 3225134
```

Phone - Sony Xperia Z

Google Play  services application - last version.
Google APIs - last version. 18 version.

Why it doesn't work.I've already searched it. Can't find the solution.
On samsung  galaxy s3 it works.

Comment: The same project doesn't work on Sony and works in Samsung

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858215/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3159100-but-found-3158130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method to check whether GooglePlayService are available or not

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 9000).show();

            } else {
                Log.i("GCM", "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Updating from playstore didn't help

Answer (score 0):

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_3225130_r10.zip Here download and install. May be bug or something else. But it  works with this library.