# "Google play services out of date" error i am running program built i 4.2.2 (API 17) running on emulator on API 17(google api)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

### Logcat

```
02-19 08:03:37.065: E/Trace(2154): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    02-19 08:03:39.306: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2154): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 3136130
    02-19 08:03:39.362: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2154): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 3136130
    02-19 08:03:39.415: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2154): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 3136130
    02-19 08:03:39.456: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2154): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 3136130
    02-19 08:03:39.482: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2154): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 3136130
    02-19 08:03:39.792: D/dalvikvm(2154): GC_CONCURRENT freed 175K, 11% free 2681K/2980K, paused 16ms+38ms, total 238ms
    02-19 08:03:39.852: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2154): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4132500 but found 3136130
    02-19 08:03:40.572: D/gralloc_goldfish(2154): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.becram.signalmapping"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    />


<permission
      android:name="com.becram.signalmapping.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.becram.signalmapping.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission   
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBELItqYIvKuo2RD5RzpmdwdUqoXx30dkU"/>


    <activity

        android:name="com.becram.signalmapping.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

### acitivity_main.xml

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858215/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3159100-but-found-3158130

Comment: i couldnt find any solution there