# Android Map is not showing even on the phone only white screen is seen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-maps-v2

My Project has a map activity with other activities linked using intent. However all other activities are been seen; Map just shows a blank white screen on phone and error" update google play services" on the emulator. please help

ActivityMap.java

```
package com.example.bloodbankmap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class ActivityMap extends FragmentActivity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
           // googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    //R.id.map)).getMap();
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



 <!--   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="View Complete Stock " /> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bloodbankmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/blood"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.List"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.ActivityMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
          </activity> 

     <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Registration"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Area"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Disp_bb"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Nearest_BB"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Notifications"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.Notify"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

   <activity
            android:name="com.example.bloodbankmap.SByBlgrp"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>


        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD-0S4belIQQUFoYL26Y_fimoS6FZ4udpE" />
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my logcat

```
02-20 06:07:15.317: D/dalvikvm(1022): GC_CONCURRENT freed 272K, 15% free 2489K/2904K, paused 17ms+3ms, total 62ms
02-20 06:07:15.317: D/dalvikvm(1022): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 46ms
02-20 06:07:15.327: I/dalvikvm-heap(1022): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.254MB for 721184-byte allocation
02-20 06:07:15.377: D/dalvikvm(1022): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 12% free 3191K/3612K, paused 48ms, total 49ms
02-20 06:07:15.557: I/Choreographer(1022): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:15.597: D/gralloc_goldfish(1022): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-20 06:07:52.841: D/dalvikvm(1161): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 251K, 14% free 2489K/2884K, paused 36ms, total 38ms
02-20 06:07:52.841: I/dalvikvm-heap(1161): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.253MB for 721184-byte allocation
02-20 06:07:52.901: D/dalvikvm(1161): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 12% free 3191K/3592K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
02-20 06:07:52.961: D/dalvikvm(1161): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 3191K/3592K, paused 5ms+25ms, total 65ms
02-20 06:07:53.101: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:53.151: D/gralloc_goldfish(1161): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-20 06:07:55.442: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:55.811: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 399 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:55.841: D/dalvikvm(1161): GC_CONCURRENT freed 731K, 24% free 2858K/3732K, paused 6ms+43ms, total 163ms
02-20 06:07:57.901: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 2434 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:58.231: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:58.392: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 175 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:58.571: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:07:59.131: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.181: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.241: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.281: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.321: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.351: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.391: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.422: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.461: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.651: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.681: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.781: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.821: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.902: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:07:59.961: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1161): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:08:00.021: D/dalvikvm(1161): GC_CONCURRENT freed 317K, 20% free 2993K/3732K, paused 15ms+58ms, total 255ms
02-20 06:08:00.081: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 157 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:08:00.351: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 128 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:08:00.641: I/Choreographer(1161): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:56:51.331: E/Trace(1652): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-20 06:56:51.991: D/dalvikvm(1652): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 262K, 14% free 2489K/2892K, paused 87ms, total 89ms
02-20 06:56:52.001: I/dalvikvm-heap(1652): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.253MB for 721184-byte allocation
02-20 06:56:52.061: D/dalvikvm(1652): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 12% free 3191K/3600K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
02-20 06:56:52.131: D/dalvikvm(1652): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 3191K/3600K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 71ms
02-20 06:56:52.301: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:56:52.331: D/gralloc_goldfish(1652): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-20 06:56:54.451: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:56:54.801: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 382 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:56:54.821: D/dalvikvm(1652): GC_CONCURRENT freed 731K, 24% free 2858K/3732K, paused 5ms+22ms, total 146ms
02-20 06:56:55.001: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:56:55.651: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:56:56.032: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:03.691: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:04.301: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.351: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.411: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.441: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.491: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.531: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.611: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.651: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.881: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:04.931: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:05.082: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:05.131: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:05.231: D/dalvikvm(1652): GC_CONCURRENT freed 292K, 20% free 2987K/3732K, paused 6ms+38ms, total 256ms
02-20 06:57:05.241: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:05.291: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1652): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 06:57:05.371: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:05.681: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:07.101: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:07.271: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:14.221: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:14.971: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:15.516: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:16.541: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 06:57:17.311: I/Choreographer(1652): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:21.421: D/dalvikvm(1811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 15% free 2491K/2916K, paused 17ms+6ms, total 105ms
02-20 07:35:21.421: D/dalvikvm(1811): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
02-20 07:35:21.442: I/dalvikvm-heap(1811): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.256MB for 721184-byte allocation
02-20 07:35:21.492: D/dalvikvm(1811): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 12% free 3191K/3624K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
02-20 07:35:21.751: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:21.781: D/gralloc_goldfish(1811): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-20 07:35:23.801: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:24.181: D/dalvikvm(1811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 731K, 24% free 2854K/3728K, paused 6ms+70ms, total 146ms
02-20 07:35:24.201: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 462 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:24.391: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:24.941: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:25.351: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:25.982: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:26.501: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.551: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.581: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.631: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.671: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.711: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.751: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.781: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.821: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:26.981: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:27.001: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:27.241: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:27.281: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:27.361: D/dalvikvm(1811): GC_CONCURRENT freed 276K, 20% free 3003K/3728K, paused 69ms+48ms, total 281ms
02-20 07:35:27.372: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:27.411: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1811): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4242000 but found 3136130
02-20 07:35:27.502: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:27.771: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:29.351: I/Choreographer(1811): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:30.241: D/AndroidRuntime(1811): Shutting down VM
02-20 07:35:30.251: W/dalvikvm(1811): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 07:35:33.941: D/dalvikvm(1825): GC_CONCURRENT freed 250K, 14% free 2589K/2984K, paused 74ms+4ms, total 156ms
02-20 07:35:34.101: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:34.111: D/gralloc_goldfish(1825): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-20 07:35:34.373: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 213 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:35.283: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:36.031: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:36.081: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:36.191: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:36.281: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:36.684: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-20 07:35:36.831: I/Choreographer(1825): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: is your apikey right. try generating a new one

Comment: Go to SDK Manager and update Google Play Services, a new update was released

Comment: my google play services arre already updated

Comment: plz try into a real device

Comment: o
 
it is even not working on the phone; it just shows a blank white screen; however it shows searching for gps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot emulate google maps on the emulator you just need a real device for working with maps, since adt emulator don't have google play services installed, just make sure google services are updated your api key is not wrong and go test your app on a real device , however this must be known I searched and found this [Link](http://javamvp.blogspot.com/2013/06/put-android-maps-v2-work-on-your.html) go see it they describe how you car run the Google Maps in the emulator.

I have updated my answer and showed my code it is little different from yours but may it help you

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;
MapView mMapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview);

        // 1- get reference to MapView
        mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        // 2- MapView has the same life cycles as the Activity 
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Test and check if Google Play Services is available 
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

activity_mapview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Adds a mapView to the layout -->
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY_IS_NOT_PUBLIC"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

see the following link too [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858215/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3159100-but-found-3158130)

Comment: you need a real device for testing work with google maps api I had the same issue since no google play services are found on the emulator

Comment: it is even not working on the phone; it just shows a blank white screen; however it shows searching for gps

Comment: Can you post the logcat output here ?

Comment: I have updated my answer wish your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Either your api key has been generated using a SHA1 fingerprint , which has not been generated from your computer i.e a fingerprint mismatch is occuring.
Or you are providing a wrong api key.

Also update your Google Play Services in sdk.

Comment: i have created a proper sha1 fingerprint from my own computer and also updated google play services to the latest one

Comment: in Android Api Console , did you turned on the Map APi V2 toggle button ?

Comment: YES THE API V2 BUTTON WAS ON

Answer (score 1):

from ur `logcat` I see

> 02-20 07:35:30.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1811):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?

Actually, the problem relates to `Gingerbread` and `older phones` using `the wrong URI` if they don't already have the `Play Store installed`. This isn't a safe assumption. Most out-of-the-box Gingerbread phones don't come with it, and Google updates don't necessarily install it. [See the discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42543)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42543

[U can get answer for this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator/17036337#17036337)

Comment: BUT I AM WORKING ON JELLYBEAN

Comment: have checked `2nd link I provided` :( except that don't find any thing else regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing fill_parent with match_parent in your layout, fill_parent has been deprecated after android 2.2
 Also, try regenerating the api key.
what device are you testing on?

Comment: samsung galaxy grand DUOS and i tried changing it to match_parent but to no help

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem Is SHA1 Key ,

1.Get The API Key And Update it your google_maps_api.xml file.
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_4_get_a_google_maps_api_key

2.Generate Sha1

```
>Open Android Studio.
>Open Your Project.
>Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
>Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar , you will see List
 Gradle scripts of your Project)
>Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List(root))
>Click on Tasks
>Click on android
>Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
```

[How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)

3. clean project
   in android studio 
   menu > build > clean project

4.Run application on your phone or emulator