# Why doesn't the MapView of Google Maps appear in my Android Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

What I am trying to do is display a Google Maps view when I click on a list item in my NavigationDrawer. The way I have it set up is that whenever I click on a list item, then the current fragment is replaced with a new one.

So, when I click on "Find Stores" list item, my StoreMapFragment replaces the current fragment.

The problem I am having is that the Google logo and zoom-in and zoom-out buttons appear on the bottom of the screen, but the actual map itself will not show.

I have looked at many of the guides for the Google Maps Android API v2 and similar issues & questions asked on StackOverflow. I have also tried doing this using an activity, but I get the same results.

At first, I didn't see any errors in the stack trace. Now this is what it says:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fv4.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.fv4.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.fv4.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Teatimefinal">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAxwMnDDx7pP23x3sB8ZqACsXC3MUDfE7c" />

          </application>

</manifest>
```

StoreMapFragment.java

```
public class StoreMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.store_map_frag);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (mapView != null) {
            googleMap = mapView.getMap();

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

//            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        }

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();

        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/store_map_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what my screen looks like:

[image: MapView]

Comment: `android:uses-permission` -> `uses-permission`. Also, post logs.

Comment: I did some work on Google Maps (android) before and I have the sample code at https://github.com/echirchir/kenyapp - this should help you a bit

Comment: @njzk2 At first I didn't see errors, but I took another look, and now posted the stack trace

Comment: Maps has its own LogCat output. Look for that and post it if you're still having trouble. Also double-check your [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key). Sometimes weird stuff happens with that. **Edit:** Yes, your stack trace says "Authentication Error", which means that something is wrong with your API key. Try re-generating it.

Comment: @sonictt1 OK. It seems that the error is with the API Key, according to the stack trace. I find it odd though, because I know the API Key exists.

Comment: @Freddie_V4 It is odd. I've had problems with the API keys, myself.

Comment: Try regenerating it perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I figured out the problem. The issue was with the SHA-1 fingerprint. I realized that I was using the wrong SHA-1. I actually used the example SHA-1 from [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key). So, I decided to look on StackOverflow on how to get my own SHA-1, here: [How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)

And now I can see the map.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stack trace, something weird happened with your API key. It seems to be a pretty common problem. I've had to deal with weird API key stuff, myself. [Link here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key) for more info.