# google maps V2 “Unfortunately app has Stopped”

Tags: android, xml, api, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I just begin to learn Android .take 4 days to try work maps view but not work .that error Unfortunately the app has stopped
[image: manifest]

[image: manifest]

[image: mainActivty.java]

[image: activity]

Comment: Can you post the logcat message.

Comment: there alot of message and i cant copy it cuz i work with  BlueStacks as emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things you need to check:

`1.` Is the SHA1 fingerprint is ok that you have registered in `google api console`.For how to find it , you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)
`2.` The generated `api_key` must be same with the `menifest`.
`3.` Name of the app in api console must be same with the name of app in `strings.xml`.
`4.` `meta-data` must have to be included in `menifest`.

```
<meta-data 
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

**I recommend you to follow this [link](http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Building-Mobile-Apps-Google-Maps-Android-API-v2/133347-2.html).It is awesome and it will take just 1 hour for you to map working.**

Comment: Just adding #4 worked for me, thanks. I don't know why at this stage, but most tutorials I've followed don't include that line.

Answer (score 2):

For google map to work add below lines to your manifest -

```
<meta-data 
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and import google play service library to your workspace.

Comment: G:\Andy\mapsss\AndroidManifest.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

Comment: have ypu added google play service lib in your project as a support library?

Comment: yes i followed that links 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614946/Android-google-map-api-v-setup?msg=4786519#xx4786519xx
http://umut.thttps://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_keyekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: While importing have you 'check' copy project in workspace 'checkbox'. Please verify your project and  library project are in same directory.

Comment: i did it and it is added in package explorer

Comment: then open manifest of library project and copy version code and paste it to your manifest at the place of @integer/google_play_services_version it will work

Comment: why it not load any map ??

Comment: have you generate api key correctly and activate google map api v2 service to google app console.

Comment: i think you have not activate map api service.

Comment: i activate Google Maps Android API v2 in services 
and generate code