# Google PlacePicker Closes Immediately After Launch

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places

I am developing an Android Application and was looking into Google Places for some functionality within the application. Google has recently released the PlacePicker feature which is what I am using. I have followed the Google guidelines and quick start guides to the "T". The functionality was working amazing as of three hours ago and now when I go to test it, it launches and then immediately closes with no errors thrown in the stack trace. Here is how I am using the code:

This is within a fragment.

```
// The Location Selection from Google Place Picker
where.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            launchPlace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException |  GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

This is within the fragments onCreateView.

The method launchPlace() is defined as follows.

```
// Start Google Place Picker Code **************************************************************
public void launchPlace() throws GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException,
        GooglePlayServicesRepairableException {
    PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    String badLocation = "That location is not valid for this app, please select a valid location";

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            if (place.getPlaceTypes().contains(34)) {
                if (place.getPlaceTypes().contains(9) || place.getPlaceTypes().contains(15) ||
                        place.getPlaceTypes().contains(38) ||
                        place.getPlaceTypes().contains(67) ||
                        place.getPlaceTypes().contains(79)) {
                    where.setText(place.getName());
                    loc = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            badLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        launchPlace();
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code worked previously (3 hours ago) and now does not. Here is what LogCat says: (Android Studio)

```
04-21 15:48:02.320    5045-5045/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-21 15:48:02.680    5045-5124/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1a55600 (InsetDrawable) with handle 0xa185dff0
04-21 15:48:05.000    5045-5121/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-21 15:48:05.060    5045-5045/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@215c768a time:9757022
```

If anyone knows of a way to help with this that would be amazing, I know that Google PlacePicker is quite new but I am a novice Android Developer and feel like someone has a better understanding than I. Any and all help would be appreciated. If more information is required please let me know. We use GitHub so I have reverted all the way back to when it once worked, yet nothing changed, it still closes (the picker, not the app). I have enabled the Google Places API and Google Places API for Android in the developer console, no help there either. It gets to the "Updating your location" screen then stops.

EDIT: This is the entire LogCat, from launch (On a Samsung Galaxy S5) to the PlacePicker starting (One navigation prior to that action) then closing and returning to the app. Is this what you meant?

```
04-21 16:56:26.740  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.siliconmindtech.trofi-1/base.apk
04-21 16:56:26.910  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 16:56:26.910  27318-27340/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-21 16:56:26.910  27318-27340/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
04-21 16:56:26.910  27318-27340/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-13137-1066627414: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-21 16:56:26.910  27318-27340/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-21 16:56:26.910  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 16:56:26.940  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
04-21 16:56:26.940  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
04-21 16:56:26.950  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 16:56:26.970  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-21 16:56:27.030  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue
    Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1_20141028_021_patches2
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
04-21 16:56:27.030  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 16:56:27.050  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xa23090d8 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8
04-21 16:56:27.050  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-21 16:56:27.050  27318-27340/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
04-21 16:56:27.240  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
04-21 16:56:27.260  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi V/RenderScript﹕ 0xa2377a00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
04-21 16:56:27.310  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@344b9848 time:13859270
04-21 16:56:29.700  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-21 16:56:31.850  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
04-21 16:56:31.970  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/Places﹕ Got here!
04-21 16:56:32.300  27318-27350/com.siliconmindtech.trofi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa196d600 (InsetDrawable) with handle 0xaf7fc350
04-21 16:56:32.740  27318-27318/com.siliconmindtech.trofi I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@344b9848 time:13864703
```

The above LogCat is Verbose.

Solution: Don't be a newbie like me, I had forgotten to add my Google API Key to my android_manifest.xml... I apologize.

Comment: Show the exception in the log cat.

Comment: Printing the Exceptions to the LogCat yields no change from the above log. The sample code they have on GitHub is also broken in the same way. Experience that here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlacePicker I used the PlacePicker.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I also have the same problem. My app was working a week ago, but now it does not. I didn't change anything...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just enable **Google Places API for Android** in your Google Developer Console.

Don't forget to specify your API key at `AndroidManifest`:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="ADD_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
```

Comment: This isn't correct.  Or at least, it isn't the whole fix.

Comment: The great thing about the PlacePicker is that you don't need any API's. Google handled all of that for you, hence the usefulness of the PlacePicker. Documentation to support this answer here: https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker

Comment: @ColeLaidlaw I would like do disagree that you don'y need any APIs for `PlacePicker`. At least, the official sample app requires your API key to be specified at AndroidManifest: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlacePicker/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L49

Comment: @lbrendanl yes, the whole fix also includes a correct API key at your `AndroidManifest` I believe.

Comment: @fraggjkee you're right, looks like this should solve the problem for the original question.  My problem appears to be slightly different, the place picker works perfectly on an emulator but won't work on any physical device I've tested.

Comment: But, I'll send the bounty to you since it answered the original question, I will open another for my issue.

Comment: Yes, you need the API key to use Google services, but the actual API's do not need to be enabled. They are not enabled in my console for Google Places or Google Places for Android. That's what I meant in my previous comment followed by my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that when Google made changes to their API's on 04/20/2015 they modified the places API that the PlacePicker inherently uses. The solution that worked for me is as follows:

1. Go to your Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com/project)
2. Navigate to your project if you have made one. If not go here: https://developers.google.com/console/help/
3. Navigate to "APIs & auth" then to "Credentials" on the left side of the console. I don't have enough rep to post a picture for guidance...
4. Create a new Key, this appears under Public API access in your Credentials window. You will need your SHA1 Fingerprint to receive the key. Directions that I used are here: [How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)
5. The location that you input your SHA1 Fingerprint should be in this format:
   (Your Key, 20 Hex values separated by ":");com.yourpackage.yourapp
6. Copy your API Key that is generated. You will need to add the fingerprint of each developer in the same format above for it to work for other developers.
7. Add your key to your AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<application ...

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key" />

... </application>
```

Where the "@string/google_api_key" /> is the key that you just generated. Place it in your strings.xml file as such:

```
<string name="google_api_key">yourkeyhere</string>
```

8. Clean and Rebuild your project. Should be working now. I don't think I left any steps out... Please comment if I have.

Comment: Yes, these are the exact steps outlined in the Places API documentation.

Comment: Yes, but that was the fix that worked for me. The documentation wasn't very clear about having to follow the previous pages. When you navigate to the PlacePicker page it isn't very clear, it's actually quite vague and doesn't remind the developer to take such actions.

Comment: This works only in debug for me, not release. Once I sign the apk, it's back to the original behavior. I've even removed all SHA1 Fingerprint from the Key, and it says "Any application allowed". This is the error I get: `05-05 07:59:27.448   1622-24823/? W/Places﹕ f.a:597: gLocReplyElement unsuccessful status: 1
05-05 07:59:27.449   1622-24823/? W/Places﹕ f.a:624: gPlaceQueryResult unsuccessful responseCode: 31
05-05 07:59:27.450  23097-24837/? E/PlacePicker﹕ NETWORK_ERROR`

Comment: I personally have not attempted a release yet, when I generate the release and test I will respond with an answer. However the error is saying that the PlacePicker is returning a NETWORK_ERROR, I assume you have the Internet Access and Fine Location Permissions enabled in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @ColeLaidlaw yeah, totally do. Like I said, debug build works fine. Going to start a brand new project for the sole purpose of testing the debug vs. release build, and I will report back here also.

Comment: Brand new project worked great, debug and release versions. Turns out it's a very odd bug in the Google Developer Console Project. I had shared the particular project with a user in a "Google Apps" account. This is where things went bad. Once I removed the user (and regenerated the key), everything worked normally. I'll try to find a place to report such a bug. Hope this helps others.

Comment: @ToddDeLand - Thanks! Your solution worked well for me. I didn't remove any of our users, but I did regenerate our API key and it worked after that.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue. I add Google map key

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>` in manifest file.
```

The Place Picker closes immediately. Then, i also add

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
```

The Place Picker shows, but when i open map, my app was force close, and log like below.

```
RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fb.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:364)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzj(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzqs(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I try to remove

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>`
```

but keep

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
```

And It's working well, now, and I don't know why.

Comment: I believe the v2 was deprecated. That is why you had to switch.

Comment: I had the same problem. Turns out you should only use one or the other. Recommended you use the android.geo metadata since it supports multiple Google Maps-Api. Found the answer here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: "As shown above, com.google.android.geo.API_KEY is the recommended metadata name for the API key. A key with this name can be used to authenticate to multiple Google Maps-based APIs on the Android platform, including the Google Maps Android API. For backwards compatibility, the API also supports the name com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY. This legacy name allows authentication to the Android Maps API v2 only. An application can specify only one of the API key metadata names. If both are specified, the API throws an exception."

Answer (score 4):

replace your meta data tag in the mainfeast .. it works for me ..

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR ANDROID KEY" />
```

with

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR ANDROID KEY" />
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems using the Places API. At the end, I figured out that there are different Google Places APIs especially for Android. Consequently, the API-Key that I was using was simply for the non-Android version.

Generate your key using this link:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup

Answer (score 1):

in my case GO to Google COnsole then Enabled API for Android Google Places, then Go to Manifest.xml and put this  code under

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and dont forget to put Google API key

Answer (score -1):

How i fixed this error was when getting an API key (On Google Developers Page) , the location where you enter your package name enter your complete package name. This is available in your android manifest!