# google map not showing in my android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I actually copied all the code from my friends laptop and everthing worked completely fine except google map. What mighy be the problem? 
I have downloaded all google services.

Comment: Try to give a description of the problem and post relevant logs. "it doesn't work" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every debug compiler for every single computer is different. You can create a new key here:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true

or add the new SHA1 to the existed project. Remember, to get the necessary key, you must do the follow:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Also, you must do the same for the final key when you make a release apk.

EDIT: You can also follow this example to generate a new key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27639043/3743245