# Issues in login with gmail and generating SHA1 key in android

Tags: android, sha1

I am trying to create an android app in which user can login with their gmail account. The steps that I have followed are:

1. Created a Google Developers Console project.
2. Next to create the client ID, I need to provide the package name and SHA1 key as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)

My problem is when I am using an SHA1 key, it says "The signing fingerprint you specified is already used by another Android OAuth2 client."

I have googled about this issue and found that it is because i am already using the same SHA1 key for another project.

Now the problem is I am not clear with the concept of SHA1 key.In my knowledge, every project will have its own SHA1 key(which is some type of encrypted key for a particular project). I have found some commands for generating SHA1 key, but I cant find a good description about the variables used in generating this key.

Somehow I got a command to generate a keystore file (I am not clear about what it does). I am stuck here. I don't know whether I can get a SHA1 key from this keystore or not. So how should I generate a valid SHA1 key for a particular project? Please provide a better description for SHA1 key also if possible.

Comment: using eclipse or studio? and ccheck your package name in manifest..

Comment: using android studio

Comment: but is that related with our IDE? I just need to create a valid SHA1 key

Comment: cuz in eclipse you can get it from Window>Pref>Android>Bulild...goodluck then

Comment: Ok, but I am using android studio

Comment: go to cmd and paste the below command `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\abc\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`  replace `abc` with your pcs username

Comment: Then use commnad prompt ..see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of googling I got this command: 
    "keytool -list -v -keystore "myapp.keystore"

We can get a unique SHA1 key for every project by specifying our keystore file in this command.