# Use Google Maps api without adding fingerprint

Tags: android, google-maps

In [this article](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/apiKey.html) it says that the device fingerprint needs to be added. But isn't that a bit complicated if you want to share your app with a lot of people? 
How can other apps display maps for all the users? Are they adding for each device the fingerprint somehow automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> In this article it says that the device fingerprint needs to be added.

No, it does not. It says:

> First you register the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate that will be used to sign your application

This certificate in on your developer machine, not the device.

Comment: So if i install an APK that has been build on a registered developer machine the map should display properly?

Comment: Ok, that means that every developers key needs to be added?

Comment: @jteichert: You only have one production signing key for the app. I would have all developers use the same debug signing key. Net: you have to register two SHA-1 fingerprints. However, with the current maps implementation (Maps V2), they can both be tied to the same API key, which means your code can remain the same whether you are doing a debug or a release/production build.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @CommonsWare answer:

When you will generate the apk for uploading in the play store, you will need to generate a keystore for signing it and you will need to add the fingerprint of this keystore.

But before generating the apk for play store, Android Studio is signing your apk with the keystore that is under "< your user directory >/.android/debug.keystore". You need to add the fingerprint of this keystore.

More info on getting the debug keystore fingerprint here: [How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)