# Android Google API Debug App working but not signed App

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, android-googleapiclient

My Android App seems to be working fine by using code given from: [google api webpage](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth#extend_asynctask_to_get_the_auth_token)

when running in debug mode but once I generated a signed apk, and uploaded the app to the app store, the app will not log in properly. Is there any way of fixing this, or even debugging an installed app as logs will not show up in android studio? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you add any SHA1 footprint to the Google developer console in order to use this service? If so, make sure you add the SHA1 footprint for your release key as well

Comment: Oh, how do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: On the link you have posted, check the **Register your app** section

Comment: You can get it using CMD commands. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode check the answer. Instead of debug.keystore give path to your release.keystore

Comment: Alright I see, and what do i put for the alias, storepass, and keypass? Are these the same as the ones set in the "Generate Signed APK" window in android studio? Thanks

Comment: @VasanthSadhasivan Yes. Give the same alias and password you put in the "Generate Signed APK" window

Comment: Alright I think that solves it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue with Google Map Api... I had solve this.
You have to generate sha-1 key using your keystore (this keystore use/ generate when you generate signed apk).

May be, the SHA1 currently you are using for debugging purpose .

So when you are creating a signed apk u have one kestore file. try to generate new SHA1 key with this new keaystore file.

then using this keystore file create API key for signed apk.

replace debug API key already stored in manifest file and google API console with the new one.

It will work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app may need to get verified by Google for the signed app to work.  They really do a poor job on error messages and making the documentation clear.  In fact, the error message that I was receiving was not even listed on their website! 
   https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
  } ],
  "code" : 403,
  "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```