# Trouble getting SHA-1 fingerprint from terminal

Tags: android, google-play-services, sha1

This is what I need it for [image]

But I am getting this error:

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: path-to-debug-or-production-keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: path-to-debug-or-production-keystore
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)

This is the place where my keytool is  c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin>
    , so I'm pretty sure I'm in the right directory when applying the command to terminal.

EDIT: I used this command in terminal :

keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v

Comment: Keystore file is not found because you have not generated it? You need to sign your application using android studio which will create a keystorefile with jks extension

Comment: Yes I just created one and tried again, but still the same error.Maybe I'm using a wrong command?

Comment: If I were you, I would put the keystore,jks file somewhere like Desktop for easy access then run that command again

Comment: Wait a minute, when you say : keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v, you are specifying the location of your keystore file right?

Comment: whats ur ide and.studio or eclipse? is ur issue with generating the sha key ?

Comment: @Eenvincible I don't know what that means I just copied it from the google  developer page(that picture that i posted) that showed me how to get the sha key

Comment: @Charuka I'm using Android Studio and my issue is that I need the sha key, but instead I'm getting an error that I posted .

Comment: for latest version of Android Studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode/67866731#67866731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your SHA key from android studio too so no worries

- open your app in android studio
- go to the Gradle(in the top right)
- click on it
  [image]
- click on your root gradle (which is same to your app name)
- expand it and expand tasks option inside it
- now expand android you will see **siginingreport** inside it
  [image]
- click on it
- details will generate for you so refresh your fingers to copy paste it :p
- you can get it from Run terminal like this and more info too depending that your requirement
- debug sha key - release sha key - ex date etc..

[image]

and finally don't forget to change your as back to run mode in here by click on it :)
[image]

cheers !

Comment: It worked, but I don't see any release keys only debug one.Well atleast now I know how to find them :D.

Comment: your app is on debug mode once you change it to release mode you can get that key from terminal too i can tell you that too but search around a bit so its god for learn if its hard add a comment ill show u how :)

Comment: I tried it just now by putting the build variant to release and even did the Build Signed Apk and after that I clicked on the signingReport, but it still shows only the debug and debugUnit variant keys and under the release variant it shows "Config: none"

Comment: in your app gradle you can change buildTypes from debug to release search about it you will find it ;) then you can get a release key too

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of Android Studio 4.2 . Follow these steps given in this answer.
**You will generate SHA Key successfully.**

*Link*:[How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode/67866731#67866731)