# How to get SHA1 fingerprint for debug mode in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, sha

Earlier it was working fine by choosing Gradle--> signing report
For reference
[Get Sha1 fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)

but in the latest stable version(2.2) its not generating by this process.
Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: try to do it through terminal

Comment: You can find it in Gradle Terminal

Comment: Any easy way? like earlier it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aftre a research I found my answer i.e need to toggle task execution/text mode. For more clarification see the image :[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method:

Generate SHA1 in terminal by the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27639043/4565874)

Answer (score 0):

This got me too - it's the Gradle Console you're looking for!

[image: Mine was in the bottom right - yours could be somewhere else]

Mine was in the bottom right - yours could be somewhere else

UPDATE:

I also notice that you can view it in the Run console by selecting the "Toggle task executions/text mode" - this will take you from the output that tells you about the gradle execution process to the actual outputs and logs from that process.

To all the people telling him to use keytool - he is looking for a way to do it within the IDE, not the first result you got when you googled..!