# Generate SHA1 Fingerprint in Android studio 2.2+

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I have just upgraded my android studio from Studio 2.1 to Studio 2.2. 
I just check all android studio 2.2 Feature and it's a great experience to work in studio 2.2, but I'm facing one problem at now.

I know it's not a problem but it occurs just because of lack of my knowledge so I apologize for that. My problem is described as below.

**Problem**

In Android studio 2.1 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode) you can easily generate SHA1. But at knowing this functionality will be change while I follow above link step then get following error.

[image: Here No Debug SHA1 Finger Print will be displayed just like 2.1]

If anyone has any idea to generate SHA1 in android studio 2.2 then please help.

I hope you are clear with my problem.Let me know if you want more information about my problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use command `keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore`

Comment: run app:signingreport

Comment: erefer here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate create google play activity,File->new->Google->google maps activity.then in that xml file you can find the SHA1 key

Comment: hey you need to open gradle console on the right bottom corner for this version of android studio

Comment: Thanks Alina.this helps me

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try following this:[How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode).

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name from List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on Android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
9. Then click this button:
   [image]

(top left of the error log)

p/s : Step 9 : You can find it in the log of `Gradle Console`

Comment: I already mention this same link in my question this link is perfect but it's only suitable for android studio 2.1 and lower.After upgrading android studio 2.2 it's not work.if you reproduce this than please upgrade android studio 2.2 and click in signingreport it not same as 2.1.

Comment: Oh woow,Thank you bro.it's working perfect.It's happens just because of lack of my knowledge.Thank you +1

Comment: wooho perfect answer ;)

Comment: Couldn't find that 9-th step anywhere else.. Good answer!

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Just look at this to get SHA-1 using android studio (with pictures).
http://easybook4u.com/index.php/2017/08/25/how-to-get-sha-1-key-using-android-studio/

Comment: Not seeing the button mentioned in step 9

Answer (score 9):

```
1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Right Side Gradle (From Right Side Panel)
3. Select :app --> TASKS --> android-->signing report
4. Now at the bottom in the run window You have your SHA1, MD5 and SHA-256
```

Answer (score 6):

CLick on **Gradle** in right side of your project in Android Studio
Now you see **Gradle Project** properties is opened.
Now go through Click on **app**-->**Task**-->**android**
In android folder you see there three options 1-androidDependencies, 2-signingReport, 3-sourceSet
Double click on **signingReport** and see signingReport of your project at bottom.
Hope you got SHA1 key.

Comment: how can i get SHA1 Key for production release?

Answer (score 0):

There is one easy way, just create a MapsActivity from new Activity menu. In newly created google_maps_api.xml sha1 is written there.