# Google map Not Working in Released .apk?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have use, `fragment` for maps. and also i have putted same API key in both debug and release `google_maps_api.xml`

but it works only on debug mode. in release mode maps fragment is shown as empty. how to fix this issue.

Comment: down voters can u tell the reason?

Comment: you create new key for release mode not same key

Comment: with same format? like sha1-fingerprint;packagename?

Comment: first create SHA1 Fingerprint based on your app play store .keystore file and same package name

Comment: it works well in debug mode

Comment: i know that one only for debug mode if you want to release mode you need to follow release procedure and debug mode key valid only one year only

Comment: release procedure ? any difference between that?

Comment: yes that based on your play store jks based you can search google map release android

Comment: debug and release apk's should be signed with different keystore files. Map api key changes depends on your keystore files. Because you create your api key with keystore sha1 fingerprint.

Answer (score 2):

referring to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

you will have 2 SHA keys ... one for debug, one for release.

just enter the SHA finger print for the release app into your console and it should work.

open your console using this link https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&reusekey=true

under credentials, enter the sha and your package names (see image below).

For my case, i use the same API key for two apps (and debug and release), hence there are 4 rows.

[image]

Comment: i cant understand `just enter the SHA finger print for the release app into your console and it should work.`

Comment: where is debug and release SHA key option?

Comment: @Chirayu, do you mean where can we get the SHA fingerprint? this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode

Comment: always sha1-finger print is same or not?

Comment: @SathishKumarJ the sha1 for debug is different from the sha1 for release.

Comment: i'm getting same sha1 while trying to get release sha1

Comment: @AngelKoh i always find same sha key.. is this only key we need always?

Comment: @Chirayu, the sha should be different for debug and release. you can try the suggestions by Naeem Ibrahim  to get the SHA key for  release http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35308827/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Pls. try this:
use adb to install the apk on your device/emulator (adb install app.apk). Don't forget to uninstall the debug version first, otherwise the signature difference will prevent the installation

Comment: how to test release apk in device?

Comment: Instead of console ,add some alerts in the application and test it locally.

Comment: By using ADB install <apk path> install the release apk by using new SHA key