# How can I work with google play service on different computer

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I got the SHA1 using this:
[How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)
and then I did a  setup for google play service and everything works fine.

When I run the app from my android studio but when I go to the other pc and tries to run the app its says `"failed to sign in"`. So my question is how can I work in two different workstation and have the same signed app? I also tried to sign the app with the `Build > Build signed APK` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you running the app in debug mode via Android Studio, the apk is signed with the debug key. For each computer, the debug key is different. The debug key is placed in `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`. So you need to use the same debug key by copying the key to another computer.

To build an apk with signed key, you need to generate your key first. Please see in [Sign your release build](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you are using the same key to sign the APK. Transfer the KeyStore (.jks) file to the new computer you'd like to sign the app on. Be sure to enter the correct password which you assigned when creating the KeyStore as well. For more information, see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).