# Can't get MD5 and SHA256 from keytool release keystore android

Tags: android, security, hash, keystore, android-keystore

First of all i know how to get md5 and sha256 using command line keytool.
I have tried [to get md5 and sha256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290681/android-studio-only-gives-me-sha1-i-need-sha256)
But when i try to get it using keytool it shows only one fingerprint SHA1.
check the screenshot below.
[image: snap]

please help me i have tried everything on internet but not found such issues.

Comment: What is the output when you add `-v` before -list, such as `keytool -list -v -keystore ...`

Comment: @davidsatchell Thank you so much it works :)