# Linux SHA256 checksum generates incorrectly encoded output

Tags: linux, encoding, checksum

I'm trying to verify the checksum of a couple of Android app APKs. I'm working in a Linux environment.

For one of the files, this command worked fine:

```
sha256sum filename
```

But for the other file (the Signal app APK), I got the following output:

```
f2f3fe7538608f2a6c43022f09216093fffb6b37e2ffed196afe4432cdb08d71
```

I was aiming for this output:

```
29:F3:4E:5F:27:F2:11:B4:24:BC:5B:F9:D6:71:62:C0
EA:FB:A2:DA:35:AF:35:C1:64:16:FC:44:62:76:BA:26
```

This seems to be an encoding issue (assuming the APK is legit), but I'm not sure how to generate the output in the correct encoding.

Comment: `sha256sum` always outputs hexadecimals only, without any separators or delimiters. But if you look at the first byte (`f2` and `29`), you'll notice that they are different.

Comment: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/11872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at is the APK fingerprint and not the sha-256 checksum.

See the following answer for obtaining that via the keytool (a Java keystore tool)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290810/6645076