# Create a secure ContentProvider (Custom) get SecurityException after adding knownSigner

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contentprovider, android-securityexception

I have 2 applications (different signing keys) which I want to have secure content provider between these 2 apps, I researched and the conclusion was using permission like below:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.myapplication.READ_PERMISSION" android:protectionLevel="signature|knownSigner" android:knownCerts="@raw/known_certs" tools:targetApi="s" />
```

The content provider works if I write it like

```
<permission android:name="com.example.myapplication.READ_PERMISSION" />
```

But if I use knownSigner then I get below error:

```
​java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.example.myapplication.CustomProvider from ProcessRecord{c4924bb 23886:package.name/u0a701} (pid=23886, uid=10701) requires com.example.myapplication.READ_PERMISSION or com.example.myapplication.READ_PERMISSION
```

And this is how *known_certs.xml* looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<certificates>
    <certificate>
        <alias>androiddebugkey</alias>
        <sha1>SHA1 CODE</sha1>
    </certificate>
</certificates>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I could find the issue and fixed it:

1. We don't need `known_certs.xml` file
2. We should use `SHA-256` hash
3. `SHA-256` must not contains `:` between it's characters
4. We can have just one or multiple hash codes per permission

Single certificate:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.READ_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|knownSigner"
    android:knownCerts="SHA256 HASH"
    tools:targetApi="s"/>
```

Multi certificates

create a string array inside `strings.xml` like :

```
<string-array name="known_certs">
    <item>HASHCODE1</item>
    <item>HASHCODE2</item>
</string-array>
```

then the permission will be:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.READ_PERMISSION"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|knownSigner"
    android:knownCerts="@array/known_certs"
    tools:targetApi="s"/>
```

Comment: How did this work for you?
I am getting this error on both Android Studio (electric eel version) and JetBrains IDE
`value=(knownSigner), acceptable delimiter-separated values are (normal|dangerous|signature|signatureOrSystem|privileged|system|development|appop|pre23|installer|verifier|preinstalled|setup|ephemeral|instant|runtime|oem|vendorPrivileged|textClassifier|wellbeing|documenter|configurator|incidentReportApprover|appPredictor|companion|retailDemo)`

Comment: nvm had to do a gradle update to get it fixed (using Android studio electric eel version)

Comment: What commands do I need to use to create the hash from my debug keystore?

Comment: @AndrewKelly 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290810/2042353