# How to get SHA-1 key in Android Studio 2.3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1

When I try

```
gradle(Right corner): My_project: app: click on tasks: android: signingReport
```

it doesn't give me any key or anything expected. I am not able to get SHA-1 key in Android Studio 2.3.1.

I get this:

```
Run build   761ms   
Run init scripts    23ms    
Configure settings  1ms 
Configure build 343ms   
Project :   343ms   
Resolve dependencies :classpath 331ms   
Calculate task graph    355ms   
Project :app    352ms   
Resolve dependencies :app:classpath 0ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:_debugApk 78ms    
Resolve dependencies :app:_debugCompile 12ms    
Resolve dependencies :app:_releaseApk   14ms    
Resolve dependencies :app:_releaseCompile   59ms    
Resolve dependencies :app:_debugUnitTestApk 2ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:_debugUnitTestCompile 2ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:releaseWearApp    1ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:wearApp   0ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:_releaseUnitTestApk   1ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:_releaseUnitTestCompile   1ms 
Resolve dependencies :app:_debugAndroidTestApk  17ms    
Resolve dependencies :app:_debugAndroidTestCompile  2ms 
Run tasks   10ms    
:app:signingReport  4ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you get instead?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try following this:[How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode).

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
6. Click on Tasks
7. Click on Android
8. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
9. You can find it in the log of `Gradle Console`

Comment: Oh Man !!! I didn't notice that Gradle Console. You are right.Thanks Man !!! You saved a lot of time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

> Find signingReport from From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar

[image]

> Double Click on signingReport

You can find it in the log of Gradle Console

[image]

Comment: Great answer, also useful if you need SHA1/256 for something else than Google Maps API

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following steps if none of the solution works to get SHA-1 key. Working solution

**1.** **File->New->google->Google Map Activity** once created one dialog will appear you will get all the details like package name, SHA key etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can just take a new **MapsActivity** in android-studio and then goto **google_maps.api.xml** and then you can get SHA-1 key