# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when using same debug keystore as before

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

We are finally migrating from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio 2.3.2 (yes, I know).

We used a custom debug keystore in Eclipse 
[image: Image of the custom debug keystore settings in Eclipse]

I am attempting to use a debug keystore in Android Studio / gradle.

I followed the straightforward directions here: [Android Developer: App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)
[image: Image of app Signing properties in Android Studio]
[image: Image of Build Type properties in Android Studio]

All the Run configuration settings are defaults.

But when I try to run, I get the following failure:

```
Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package --redacted-- signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
```

Yes, I *could* uninstall the app from my device and reinstall to get it working. **But I don't want to.** I thought the point of having and using a keystore is that you don't have to do that?

Why am I getting INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE even though I'm using the same debug keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/1703677) led me to my own answer. I ran the signing report on my project and found that all my modules were using the "default" .android/app.keystore

I went into each of my modules and added the debug signing config. I was able to Run without any further problems.