# Android. Firebase: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore

Tags: android, firebase

Windows 10

Firebase
I want to create Firebase project.
So I use this official documentaion: 
[Manually add Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Steps:

1. Go to Firebase consle
2. Click create new project
3. Create new applications
4. Select Android
5. Input name: com.myproject
6. I need to input debug signing certificate SHA-1:

Here screen:
[image: Debug signing cert SHA-1]

So I open shell and input:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

But I get error:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ~/.android/debug.keystore
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:745)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

What is wrong?
In my home folder no file "debug.keystore". So how I can get hash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Android Studio will do the SHA key generating part to save your time and effort.
You've to find Gradle Project tab somewhere at the right edge of your Android studio. Open it up.

[image]

Under your project(root)>Tasks>android, find something called `signingReport` and run it by double clicking on it.

[image]

You will find your SHA1 and MD5 certificates in the Run section, below.

[image]

Copy the SHA1 and use it. Otherwise, debug signing certificate SHA-1 is optional in this case, so you can continue without this.

Comment: ..if you still don't see it, after running signingReport .. click "Gradle Console" on the lower right side

Comment: If you do not see it, On the console window , click the 'Toggle tasks executions/text mode' icon in the left top corner of it

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this, go to the right side of your android studio and then double click the **signingReport**
[image: gradle]
and you will find the SHA-1 here,
[image: sha1]
hope this help your problem

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried out [this guide](http://android-er.blogspot.dk/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html) as suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/5359331)?

> keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

**Edited:**
A rather extensive guide on the same topic have been made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/5359331). I've personally succeeded with this on Win10 in Android Studio.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but if you are using Android Studio, you can try out my recent edit.