# How to regenerate new SHA1 key for other projects

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase, sha1

I cannot link my android app project with firebase console. Because every time when I create a new project and generate an SHA-1 key, it generates same key for every project.
I stuck in it and didn't find an answer. Please Help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are doing mistake while generating the SHA-1 Key, as we know there already located **debug.keystore** for default keystore use, so when ever you fire the code for SHA-1 then there default keystore (**debug.keystore**) will use.

so may be due to this reason you have every time same SHA-1.

Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/1201441), here describe how to find the SHA-1 using Android Studio also inside android studio.

Comment: I did the same as described in the link but all in vain  :(

Comment: i got the solution TejaDroid :)
I delete the debugkeystore from my "users/.android/" then i rebuild the project again and now a new SHA1 key has been generated <3

Comment: This comment should be the solution. Thank you @danyRoyal