# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified

Tags: keytool

```
Book-Pro:main vy$ keytool -exportcert -list -v \
> -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both 
-exportcert and -list were specified.
```

I am trying to create a SHA1 on MBP for an android Firebase project.
I pull the command from the Firebase console as described...
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

and I get an error.
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both 
    -exportcert and -list were specified.

I have tried hand typing this thinking that perhaps there is a problem with the browser.  I installed new JDK...  not sure what is going wrong here.  assistance please

Comment: I sort of fixed it... but Id still like comment.
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
observe I removed the -exportcert part.    and I did get a sha1 back

Comment: New duplicate but different wording (I didn't find this through search) - so will help getting to the answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59505659/7483211
Interestingly, when you Google just the error message this question doesn't show up at all - presumably because the error message is generic and also occurs in other situations.

Answer (score 29):

I sort of fixed it... but Id still like comments.

*For Linux / UNIX:*

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

*For Windows:*

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore
```

observe I removed the `-exportcert` part and I did get a sha1 back

Comment: Although this indeed gave me a sha1, the sha1 is different from when I get it from the `signingReport` gradle task (cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/3108590)). And when I add this sha1 into the Google Cloud Platform (in my case, for a Google Sign-In), it appears as not valid. If anyone has another solution to fix this issue, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Agree, I've faced the same problem(

Comment: Your command works but this one adds the default password already in the command which makes things even less error prone and faster: ```keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android```

Answer (score 1):

for release key this one solved my problem

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following command worked.

```
keytool -keystore C:\Users\hp\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```