# Getting fingerprint for Android keystore certificate on Mac

Tags: android, macos, google-oauth, keytool

I'm following [Google's tutorial](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#installedapplications&android) on how to set up OAuth 2.0. The documentation asks me to find the debug certificate fingerprint with the following command in the terminal:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

This doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.
```

What's the correct command on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command provided in the tutorial works for Windows (apparently) but not for Mac. However, this one works like a charm on Macs:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

It adds the default password `android` already in the command which saves one from typing. I hope Google will fix the documentation.

Output should look like:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: 23 Nov 2019
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Issuer: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Sat Nov 23 14:57:45 CET 2019 until: Mon Nov 15 14:57:45 CET 2049
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: xxxxxx
     SHA256: xxxxxx
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /Users/cornelius/.android/debug.keystore -destkeystore /Users/cornelius/.android/debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

Credit: @JoeNCA https://stackoverflow.com/a/28350434/7483211