# Google map does not load at all, without any error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services, google-places

Google map is still blink and does not load. All the scripts, api key and code are correct.

The app `gradle` file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.muzammil.bustracking"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am running app on actual Android phone , not emulator.

A lot of Thanks in advance for the answer...

Comment: did you add permissions to the manifest file?

Comment: Dear also avoid "+" in library this is bad practices add proper version number.

Comment: of course sir I've added permissions. the map is now working on emulator,, but on actual phone it is still blink

Answer (score 1):

I finally came to a solution.

Actually I was running the app on Android device with API level 24, while the app was using API level 26. I changed the target SDK version from 26 to 24 from **File > Project Structure > app > flavors**, at it worked.

Thank you to everybody helped! I really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using wrong API key.Not displaying usually happens because of it.

[This guide is a quick start to adding a map to an Android app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

In manifest for it to work under the application> tag

Comment: thank u sir it worked for emulator.. but in actual device the map is still blink

Comment: Maybe try adding this to your onMapReady

.setMapType(Google map.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)

And double check your API key

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have mentioned below permission in androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You must have API key in your project. The key can be obtained from this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).
Also you have to enable API from [GCP itself](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?pli=1). This requires SHA key for your machine which can be generated using [android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode).

Comment: all these things are well sir! while debugging it takes me to 'looper.java' class and show this message "byte code does not match the source code"