# Signed .apk not working where debug .apk works fine

Tags: android

I am facing a problem of my android app(online streaming app). I had to make an app in which performs online video streaming. It has firebase phone number authentication. my problem is that the debug app is working properly but the signed apk is not working properly at authentication section. it does not send verification code. please help me out configure it..

Comment: Show your gradle file

Comment: Have you added SHA in firebase console while authenticate ?

Comment: @HichemRomdhane

buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

Comment: yes, i have added SHA . Authuntication works fine for debug apk. but problem in signed apk @Piyush

Comment: You need to use your SHA with release mode. The SHA you have added is degug SHA which will not work. You need to generate SHA using release key store file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/5901903

Comment: @piyush , i dont know how to generate SHA using release key store file.. please help me if possible..

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate/15727931)

Comment: @Piyush..
Thanks.. It's working fine now..

Answer (score 1):

Often, this kind of problem is linked with the android permissions. The app works fine in debug mode because android is "allowing" your phone by default.
Try to add the "android.permission.INTERNET" in your android manifest and try to deploy the app again.

Hope this is helpful, good luck

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

permission is already given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **SHA1 of your release key store** file in firebase console.

you can get SHA1 with follow command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

eg:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\me\Desktop\release.jks -alias sample
```