# Android Studio is not looking proper

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is how it is supposed to look

[image]

But this is how mine currently looks and I do not know what happened or what I did wrong

[image]

When I click on Gradle, instead of showing me what it shows in the proper image it just says there is nothing to show. Could this be an install error? Or is there a setting I did not click?
[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hEEq.png)
I wanted to get my debug certificate and a post I saw said the easiest way was to click on the gradle in the top right but when I try this it just shows what is in the third picture
[How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode/34223470#34223470)

The top answer is what I tried to follow

Comment: Copy and paste the error you're getting here.

Answer (score 1):

Choose

> Window > Restore Default Layout.

Or alternatively, you can do this by pressing SHIFT+F12

Also, choose **Android** in Project View

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQRw.png

Click on the box I've indicated with the arrow. Choose "TagAlong" from the dropdown instead of the option you have selected.

With the option you currently have selected, you're telling Android Studio to build your build.gradle file and nothing else. This is a mistake I made early on and it took me hours to figure out.

Also, you're in Project view when you probably want to be in Android view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqjJz.png