# How can I get MD5 signature from a project?

Tags: android, keytool

I used keytool to get signature, it prints **SHA1**, **SHA256**, but no **MD5**.
I have viewed all the topics from StackOverflow, every reply ask to add `-v` or `-list` to give MD5 signature, but my `keytool` just don't give the MD5 signature.
I used the command below.

```
 keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the apk file

Comment: yes, i generated a signed apk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/10182897 answer already available just follow this step as you can see screen 5 there is md5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Gradle</kbd> in the right of your Android Studio > <kbd>Project name</kbd> >  <kbd>app</kbd>  > <kbd>Tasks</kbd> > <kbd>android</kbd> > <kbd>signing Report</kbd> > <kbd>Double click</kbd>

Now see the MD5 signature from Run Tab(in Left Bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the apk file and go to the META-INF folder, you will find .RSA files.

In cmd use keytool to print cert info with below command :

```
    keytool -printcert -file "Path to CERT.RSA"
```

This will print certificate fingerprints as below :

```
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  ********************5
         SHA1: *****************************2
         SHA256: *******************************12:23
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
```

Comment: keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path to CERT.RSA (No such file or directory)