# Am I supposed to edit the google-services.json file?

Tags: android, firebase

I got an email from Google that says:

> We have detected a publicly accessible Google API key associated with the following Google Cloud Platform project

and they point at the api key inside my `google-services.json` file and at a url of someone hosting my apk.

The `google-services.json` file is just what I got when following the Firebase instructions and put it where it said to put it. So did I do something wrong?

Comment: No you are not supposed to edit it, you have to [restrict](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) it

Comment: Thank you, I have now restricted it to my Android app and iOS app. I will have to analyze it a bit more before restricting APIs. I'm surprised they weren't restricted to start with considering they asked for SHA1 of the apk already. If you want to make an answer about this then I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not supposed to edit it, you have to [restrict](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) it.

Note that if you are using Android Studio, you can get the signing report see [this accepted answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)