# When I generate apk and install in my device that time I try to verify my mobile number using firebase otp show SHA-1 error

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I'm installing app from android studio everything works correctly, but when I generate apk and install app on my device and verify my mobile number using `Firebase OTP` shows error:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase authentication please verify that the correct package name and sha-1 are configured in the Firebase console

Comment: are you using the signed apk in your device ?

Comment: yes im used signed apk

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you include SHA-1 key in your firebase console configuration for phone auth.  To get a key,check out this solution..https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/5985401.
Copy the key and paste in your app's configuration on firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not added SHA-1 fingerprint of signed app which is different from debug app . Follow the below procedure to add SHA-1

-> Open your Firebase Console .

-> Click on the gear icon near **Project Overview** .

-> In **General** tab move down to **Your Apps**

-> You will see **Add Fingerprint** button there

You can generate SHA1 for released/signed app using the command below :

> keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}

Example :

> keytool -list -v -keystore PATH_TO_YOUR_JKS_FILE(C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test.jks) -alias YOUR_KEY_ALIAS_NAME(test)