# not able to create hash key for android app: I get the error "keystore JKS utilize a proprietary format"

Tags: android, windows, keystore

I want to create hash key for my android app.

According to all the web this is the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl base64
```

When I execute this command on windows I get this message:

```
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. We recommend migrating to PKCS12, an industry standard format, using the "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore command ...
```

I do not know what I should do right now.

Comment: use this mehtod [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/6816307)

Comment: @hasanhasan I am not able to open Gradle bar cause my project is a flutter project