# SHA-1 fingerprint certificate does not show in Android Studio for debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

My Android Studio Version is 3.6.3

1. Run project
2. Click on Gradle menu
3. Expand Gradle Tasks tree
4. Double click on android -> signingReport

But Does not show SHA-1 KEY.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690956/how-to-get-sha-1-in-android-studio-3-6-2/61691905#61691905

Comment: is it possible without generating keystore like just run sigingReport and show SHA-1 Key?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode

Comment: You can check correct answer

Answer (score 0):

gradle->app->Tasks->android->signingReport