# showing Error: Missing keystore while running signingreport from task in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, android-signing

After giving the loction of keystore in generate signed build. Then from gradle > task > signingreport was generated the it shows error in the log

```
Error: Missing keystore
```

Comment: It's basically impossible to answer this, from the amount of information given you could have literally just made a typo.  Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue in Android Stidio 2021.1.1
My solution was to press "Make Project" button (or Cntrl+F9)
Then just type "gradle signingreport" as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67866731/11305763

[Make Project button is under the green hummer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgvWR.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31301945)

Answer (score 0):

Old question so ill just add this here;

If anyone else has this issue then make sure you are running signingReport from under the app heading not the Tasks heading.

Gradle > app > Tasks > android > signingReport.