# PackageName / SHA1

Tags: android-studio, sha1

I am facing a problem of SHA1. I get check packageName/SHA1 message when trying to check my test, alpha or beta versions and of course on the release. I check the SHA1 with Android Studio, I created ID clients OAuth 2.0 and API key with the packName and SHA1 given by Android Studio but I still get the message and problem. If I install directly the APK on my tablet everything is OK.
Can someone help me I am becoming crazy !
Best regards,
Fabrice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)

Comment: Thanks. I want to make an Alpha or Beta test version to check it through a Google download but I get the message "check packagename/sha1". Do I need to release the version with v1 and v2 signatures or only v1 is OK ?