# What is the Current Version of Gradle To Connect to Firebase in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I was looking into creating an app on an android studio and currently, I am creating the login portion of it. I was watching a tutorial on how to do this and I followed all instructions but it gave me an error in the build.gradle (Module: app) file regarding connecting to Firebase to authenticate a user by email and password. I believe that the error is related to the version number in the code lines below:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.simplysnap"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0'
//The two lines below have the errors
implementation 'android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
// Until here
implementation 'androidx.support:support-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0'

}
```

The error I get when trying to connect to Firebase Authentication w/ email and password is this:
Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

What is the latest version of the two lines:
implementation 'android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
And is the syntax correct?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to connect android project with firebase just follow the step guided in the link

make sure you added the sha1 in firebase console you get the sh1 by following this link steps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/5309463

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

implementation 'android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
Use this instead
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

use this gradel

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, also, can I change the TargetSDK Version to 29 because it keeps saying that 28 isn't the latest version?

Comment: Yeah always keep the targetsdk to latest version

Comment: Okay, also I am getting an error on this line: implementation 'androidx.support:design:29.0.0' and implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0' Is this the wrong version?

Comment: You need to migrate the project to androidx then this error will gone, before you migrate take a bakcup of the project here is the link to migrate the project to androidx : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: I did that and it says that there are no uses for androidx in the project.

Comment: use this Gradle line in the updated answer of mine and replace it with yours