# Moving an android Project from pc to another, Firebase Auth problem?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i did recently moved out my app to other pc , unfortunately i got an issue with firebase authentication like it is shown below

[image]

P.S:

- i tried removing google-services.json and adding it again but it didn't fix anything

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show images of text.  Put the text into the question itself so that it's easy to read, copy and search.  With error message text, it's also a good idea to do a web search with that text.  What you're seeing is very common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error produced, it seems that you haven't changed the SHA-1 key when you switched PCs in Firebase.

How to check new SHA-1 Key:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223470/13826785

How to change on Firebase Console:

Go to your project settings

Click on your Android App

Under `SHA certificate fingerprints` click `Add Fingerprint`

Add your new SHA-1 Fingerprint

Hope this helps