# android studio not generating SHA-1 key from gradle menu

Tags: key, sha

I am trying to login with google , but when I go to generate SHA key from gradle menu in android studio then signing report file runs successfully , but do not show any information about SHA key
here is the screen shot [in this image you can see when I double click on signingReport then it runs successfully , but does not show any SHA key in console and anything else it is totally blank. please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTACY.png)

Comment: signing key is generated successfully, the right panel is missing, just drag that from right sid

Comment: see my this answer to generate SHA Key hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode/67866731#67866731