# Missing keystore android studio

Tags: android, firebase, sha1

I just copied my project from window to Linux, and I made the key on windows
when I want to run singingReport under android > task > app in side gradel
I got error Missing keystore, but it is exist in same folder that error shows.
I followed this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)