# Android Studio: Problem getting the SHA-1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, sha1

I am starting with Android Studio and generally developing apps. I have seen on some videos how to get the SHA-1 for the firbase but I don't have what the video shows on the gradle console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBibP.png)

But on the videos show this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYrKc.jpg)

What have I have to do to get a gradle console like the video

Answer (score 0):

if you are running android studio version 4.2.1

1.click gradle in right side of your project

2.your project name

3.run configurations

4.yourProjectName[signingReport]

if you are running any lower version
[follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)