# Android Studio gradle doesn't show run configurations

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I need to get the SHA-1 key for Firebase authentication for my app. But I am not able to find the 'run configurations' menu anywhere to run the signing report. However, in another one of my projects that was created in a friend's system, I can see it.
[Here's the image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY1OO.png)

[Here's the image of what is supposed to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kieJz.png)

Comment: Please do a proper research before asking your questions. 
It might help. 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode#:~:text=Click%20on%20Tasks,run%20or%20debug%20your%20application)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android 4.2 the layout has changed, this is how I generate SHA-1

**Step One** Click the `Terminal` at the bottom of Studio
[image]

**Step Two** Type `gradle signingReport` on the Terminal - (terminal will highlight this in yellow). DON'T PRESS ENTER YET
[image]

**Step Three** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac
This will process the report in a few moments

**Step Four** Scroll up to reveal `SHA-1`
[image]

Comment: @RupakYeware happy coding