# Facing SHA-1 Related problem in latest Andoroid Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio

**[I tried various time for finding SHA-1 in  searching related file or folder in gradle . but it shows only "app" which is not useful for me to find my desired task. How can I get the SHA-1 in android studio latest version?][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RoAq.png**

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode) out?

Comment: Can you explain what is the reason you are trying to get the sha1 for?

Comment: currently I am pursuing an android development course (pre recorded class) , I am trying to complete a module about firebase.  That's why .

Answer (score 1):

1. Once you are in the Android Studio IDE, **double-tap CTRL button**
2. **Run Everything** window will pop up
3. Type this: **gradle signingReport**
4. **SHA1** and **SHA256** can be seen in the output window

Comment: @abdur-rahman have you tried this?