# Can I have multiple OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for Android

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-cloud-console

Trying to implement Google sign-in using Firebase and Google Sign-in package in Flutter.

In my Google cloud console, there are 2 options for OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for the Android type.

The two options use a different SHA-1 key.

Is this a problem in any way for my implementation of Google sign-in?

[image: multiple ouath2 client ids example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with having multiple OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. However, if you need to use such an ID in your project, always make sure to use the one with the [correct SHA-1 key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode).

One thing to note is that for implementing Firebase sign-in with Google, you need to use the [Web client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started) and not the Android client ID.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed using the wrong SHA-1 key. Really appreciate it!