# Need SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to use Google Maps in Flutter, Get Error Unsupported class file major version 65

Tags: flutter, google-maps, gradle, sha1

I want to use Google Maps in my Flutter App. To restrict the Android API Key, I need a  SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. I went in the Flutter Terminal and typed "cd android" and then  ./gradlew signingReport, but I got this error message:

`Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :gradle:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
`

What can I do to resolve this error? I am new to Flutter, so I do need babysteps if possible. Thank you so much.

I was expecting to get a SHA-1 certificate fingerprint when running "cd android" and then "./gradlew signingReport", but instead I got the error.

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago. Resolved it by running `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode?rq=2