How to find SHA-1 signing key for my Android app in Android Studio?
enter image description here
I'm developing an Android app and need to find the SHA-1 signing key for my app to configure Google services
I tried checking the gradle tasks but couldn't locate the SHA-1.
Tried running the keytool command in the terminal but encountered an error: keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.
When I try to locate Gradle>Task>Android is not showing

@AMIT MAJHI You can get SHA-1 fingerprint as shown in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode
