# Google Play Service out of date error

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, updates

i've got a problem with the google-play-service. I'm using the Google-API for oAuth2 Authentication and Calendar/Gmail Information. Yesterday all worked fine, but today he tells me that i need a newer Version of Google PLay Service. Android Studio had updated any packages this morning. Here is the Error-Line from Logcat if i start to contact the GoogleAPI:

```
09-22 11:59:01.692: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2819): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9452480
```

Here is my grade.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias XXXXX
            keyPassword XXXX
            storeFile file(XXXX)
            storePassword XXXXX
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId XXXX
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            renderscriptDebuggable false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}








dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev48-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev212-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm always using com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth Version 9.6.0. I dont get where i can change the version.

I tried to Toast out my Version number and it gaves me 213XXXX with:

```
int test = R.integer.google_play_services_version;
        String test2 = test+"";
        Toast.makeText(this,test2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But the Error Messages shows me different version numbers:

```
09-22 13:28:26.145: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3334): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9452480
```

Many thanks,
j. Doe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an open issue about the error that you receive "[Google Play Services out of date on API 23](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212879&q=Google%20Play%20services%20out%20of%20date&sort=opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)" Also, this kind of issue came out during 2013 when you update your SDK to 18. Just check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858215/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3159100-but-found-3158130) of this issue to know more about it.

What can I suggest you is update your dependency on the latest version. After you update it, create a new virtual device/emulator when testing the application. Try to use the x86-64 version of API 23.